# Launching app from Unity search opens new instance every time

Tags: unity, launcher

If I use Unity search to launch an app that's already running, it always launches a brand new instance of that app. Is there a built in way for Unity to launch an existing app, if one is already running, like how Mac OS X handles it?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is already running, it will show up on the launcher panel on the left side, and you can just switch to it by clicking on the app's icon there.

Whether a "new instance" of an app is created however, depends entirely on the app itself having implemented IPC to run as a single instance, and being designed to work in this way. Several apps do this, but quite a great many do not.

If the app in question has a command line argument to create a new window (such as the `--new-window` option for *Chromium*), you can copy the application's `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` into `~/.local/share/applications/`, and edit it to add that argument to the default `Exec=` line in the file. This will cause it to open a new window (or tab, or whatever other behavior you prefer) each time you click on the app icon from the apps scope in the dash.